How do implement database lock mechnaism in springboot
I want to insert a single as record as did not exists, both records are saving instead of one, if concurrnet request with same time than save only one record.
@GetMapping("/bookslot")
    public void bookTicket() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        executor.execute(run(slotService::method1));
        executor.execute(run(slotService::method2));
        executor.shutdown();
    }

    private Runnable run(FailableRunnable<Exception> runnable) {
        return () -> {
            try {
                runnable.run();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
};
    }

repository
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    @Query("SELECT e FROM Slot e WHERE e.time = :time")
    Optional<Slot> findByTimeWithLock(@Param("time") LocalTime time);


service class
@Transactional
    public void method1() throws InterruptedException {
        saveSlot("sam", "07:00");
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }

    @Transactional
    public void method2() throws InterruptedException {
        saveSlot("Curran", "07:00");
        Thread.sleep(1000); 
    }

@Transactional
    public void saveSlot(String name, String newTime) {
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(newTime);     
        Optional<Slot> slotOptional = slotRepo.findByTimeWithLock(time);
       
        if (!slotOptional.isPresent()) {
            Slot newSlot = new Slot();
            newSlot.setName(name);
            newSlot.setTime(time);
            slotRepo.save(newSlot);
        }
    }


By the way, your code is insufficient to properly shut down an executor service. See the boilerplate code given to your in the Javadoc for ExecutorService. Or use the close method.

So you want to avoid having two rows that share the same time-of-day? Your Question is not clear.

As the time is same for parallerl request then save only one record.reject the second request

add a unique key to the column you want to prevent the duplicate and then handle the error for the one that errors out?

You can use the concurrent package's Atomic lock and utilize the test-and-set pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) to reject 2nd request only if you want to employ a design pattern within the JVM scope.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
